# Newrelic Install for WebSphere - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, websphere, newrelic

We've installed the NewRelic java agent on our WebSphere Application / WebSphere Commerce system and in the NewRelic logs we are seeing this:

```
Sep 3, 2013 22:47:53 -0400 NewRelic 14 INFO: The data collector is temporarily unavailable. This can happen periodically. In the event that availability of our servers is not restored after a period of time, then please report this to New Relic. java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.a(SSLSocketFactory.java:11)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:6)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:161)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:36)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1184)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:75)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.connectAndSend(DataSenderImpl.java:550)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.send(DataSenderImpl.java:600)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.invoke(DataSenderImpl.java:480)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.invokeNoRunId(DataSenderImpl.java:475)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.getRedirectHost(DataSenderImpl.java:203)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.connect(DataSenderImpl.java:193)
    at com.newrelic.agent.RPMService.launch(RPMService.java:194)
    at com.newrelic.agent.rpm.RPMConnectionServiceImpl$RPMConnectionTask.attemptConnection(RPMConnectionServiceImpl.java:301)
    at com.newrelic.agent.rpm.RPMConnectionServiceImpl$RPMConnectionTask.access$1100(RPMConnectionServiceImpl.java:101)
    at com.newrelic.agent.rpm.RPMConnectionServiceImpl$RPMConnectionTask$3.run(RPMConnectionServiceImpl.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLJsseUtil.b(SSLJsseUtil.java:125)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:3)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:41)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:46)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.<init>(b.java:26)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:1)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:5)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:957)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.createConnection(DataSenderImpl.java:676)
    at com.newrelic.agent.transport.DataSenderImpl.connectAndSend(DataSenderImpl.java:540)
    ... 18 more
```

There seems to be some documentation about how to update an Eclipse based IDE environment to overcome this error in other situations, but nothing specific to NewRelic. Has anyone seen this before that can offer suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The next release of New Relics Java agent should make it possible to run without any configuration changes. With version 2.21.X and earlier please submit a request for support at support.newrelic.com

Answer (score 0):

Read and see if this publication gives you a hint:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584437

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing. As you might have gathered from the article liked by Robban WebSphere has some restriction in the SSLConnectionFactory, so a quit fix would be to just edit the **newrelic.yml** and configure:

```
# The agent communicates with New Relic via https by
# default.  If you want to communicate with newrelic via http,
# then turn off SSL by setting this value to false.
# This work is done asynchronously to the threads that process your
# application code, so response times will not be directly affected
# by this change.
# Default is true.
ssl: false
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.0.0 or later of New Relic's Java Agent should completely resolve this issue without any custom configuration, certainly without turning off SSL! [Release notes.](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java)